# C# Checkbox.Checked Property Not Reflecting Check Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form with containing a datalist which is bound to a datasource which contains a list of items and a true/false flag. If true, the myCheck checkbox is checked:

```
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="save_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:DataList runat="server" id="myList" onitemdatabound="myList_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th id="thCheck" runat="server">Check?</th>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td id="tdName" runat="server"><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
        <td runat="server"><asp:CheckBox id="myCheck" runat="server" Checked="false" /></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

On clicking save, I want to see which items have been checked. I am using the following to iterate through the items in the datalist:

```
protected void save_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String Name;
    Boolean omit;

    foreach (DataListItem item in myList.Items)
    {
        CheckBox omitCheck = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("myCheck");

        if (omitCheck != null)
        {
            if (omitCheck.Checked == true) // This line is my problem!!
            {
                // do stuff
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

`FindControl` appears to work ok and returns a checkbox, however the value is always false, even if I have checked some of the boxes. If I set the value of the checkboxes to True in the aspx page, `omitCheck.Checked` is always true. `ViewState` is not disabled.

I'm new to this so sure there is an obvious answer.

Comment: what does the myList_ItemDataBound function look like? I suspect it needs a !IsPostback to not override entered values on the postback

Comment: That was it, thanks Evert. Adding a !IsPostBack check around the myList.DataBind() method has fixed it.

Comment: i'll put that as an answer then, glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what does the myList_ItemDataBound function look like? I suspect it needs a !IsPostback to not override entered values on the postback